# $state.go - update url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my Angularjs app to listen for logouts:

```
//app.js
$rootScope.$on('logout', function() {
    $http.get('/logout');
    $state.go('home'); //redirect back to homepage
});
```

The user is successfully logged out and redirected but the url does not get updated in the address bar. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Weird. By default $state.go should update location because as per router-ui documentation location property in the third param by default is true. [Check that link](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state). Otherwise you could try to force set that parameter.

```
$state.go('home', {}, {location: true});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I've noticed that if I redirect to the login state then it works as expected. I feel that because my home route has `url: '',` then it doesn't work properly

Comment: I did that first but then your homepage route has to have the # which is annoying. `http://example.com/#`